# Wrapping sequence of tiles in FlowDocument

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

Is it possible to have a `FlowDocument` contain a sequence of fixed-size tiles that wraps?

I have tried using `Floater` but can only get the following effect. Notice that the tiles are fixed-size *except for the ones on the right edge* (which have collapsed instead of falling to the next line):
[image: Tiles wrapping but being scrunched on the edge]

```xml
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Floater" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Floater}}">
            <Setter
                Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                Value="Left"/>
            <Setter
                Property="LineHeight"
                Value="1in"/>
            <Setter
                Property="Margin"
                Value="0"/>
            <Setter
                Property="Padding"
                Value="0"/>
            <Setter
                Property="Width"
                Value="1in"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            <TextBlock>
                Hello, world!
            </TextBlock>
            <Floater>
                <BlockUIContainer>
                    <Grid
                        Width="1in"
                        Height="1in"
                        Background="Blue">
                        <TextBlock
                            Foreground="Red">
                            Tile
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </BlockUIContainer>
            </Floater>
            <Floater>
                ...
            </Floater>
            ...etc
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found two possible solutions:

## `InlineUIContainer`

`InlineUIContainer` by itself appears to drop to the next line as necessary. So when you use a bunch of them together:

```xml
<FlowDocument>
    <Paragraph >
        <InlineUIContainer>
            ...
        </InlineUIContainer>
        ...
    </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

...then you get something like this:
[image: Tiles shown to be wrapping with InlineUIContainer]

If you put the `InlineUIContainer`s inside a `TextBlock` inside the `Paragraph` (and set `TextBlock.TextWrapping="Wrap"`) then the tiles will no longer evenly distribute themselves horizontally but will stack up on the side like you might expect. And you can get zero space between them by ensuring that there is no line break or other whitespace between any closing and opening tags of `InlineUIContainer`. Then it looks like this:
[image: Tiles shown to be wrapping and stacked tightly]

## `Figure`

`Figure` appears to be intended more for positioning images, but by setting its `Margin` and `Padding` to zero and giving it a fixed `Width` and setting its `HorizontalAnchor`:

```xml
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Figure">
            <Setter
                Property="HorizontalAnchor"
                Value="ColumnLeft"/>
            <Setter
                Property="Margin"
                Value="0"/>
            <Setter
                Property="Padding"
                Value="0"/>
            <Setter
                Property="Width"
                Value="1in"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            <Figure>
                <BlockUIContainer>
                    ...
                </BlockUIContainer>
            </Figure>
            ...
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</Window>
```

...then you get something like this in Scroll Mode:
[image: Tiles shown to be wrapping with Figure]

HOWEVER: in Page Mode then you get something entirely different (notice how eagerly it stacks):
[image: Tiles shown to be stacking too eagerly with Figure in Page Mode]

Another caveat is in how the `Figure`s interact with other inlines in the `Paragraph`. They can only snap to one side or the other (according to the `HorizontalAnchor` property) instead of flowing inline.

For these reasons I think `InlineUIContainer` might be the best solution.